# ExpectJ Adventure

Tags: java, shell, unix, expect, nested-if

**This is my script**

```
echo "Name:"
read name
if [ "$name" == "abcd" ]; then
    echo "correct username"
    echo "Password:"
    read password
    if [ "$password" == "pwd" ]; then
        echo "Hello"
    else
        echo "Wrong password"
    fi
else
    echo "wrong username"
fi
```

=================================================================================

This is my Java code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import expectj.*;

public class Trial {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ExpectJ exp = new ExpectJ();
        String command = "sh /root/Desktop/hello.sh";
        Spawn s = null;
        try {           
            s = exp.spawn(command);         
            s.expect("Name:");
            s.send("abcd\n");
            System.out.println("Current status: "+s.getCurrentStandardOutContents());           
            s.expect("correct username");   
            s.expect("Password:");
            s.send("pwd\n");
            s.expect("Hello");
            System.out.println("final output: " + s.getCurrentStandardOutContents());
            System.out.println("Possible errors: " + s.getCurrentStandardErrContents());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ioe\n");
        } catch (TimeoutException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("toe\n");
        } finally {
            if (s != null) 
                s.stop();           
        }       
    }
}
```

============================================================================

And this is my **OUTPUT**

```
Name:
Current status: Name:
correct username
Password:
```

============================================================================

Its not proceeding further.Its not terminating either.. I dunno why..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it..2 consecutive **s.expect()** statements can never work..So to get rid of it, a **\n** could be added..

In this case

s.expect("correct username");
s.expect("Password:");

is bound not to work.So, it should be replaced by-

s.expect("correct username\nPassword:");//This will work

Answer (score 1):

Does it work when you comment this line:

```
System.out.println("Current status: "+s.getCurrentStandardOutContents());
```

Maybe the application is "expecting" the value `"correct username"` but sees `"Current status: Name:`" instead (the output from your "debug" line). Not an expert on jExpert, but if the tool just redirects and monitors the `System.out`, it will see the script output as well as everything you print to the console.

Comment: Yes that line works because it's printing the output.I guess there is no problem with that..Because the control is coming to s.expect("Password:"); ,but its not succesfully taking pwd from the script..I don't understand why that's happening..

Comment: The control is not coming to s.send("pwd\n");